# VBA Conditional Formatting with changable conditions

Tags: excel, vba, formatting, conditional-statements, cells

I am trying to set conditional formatting in 18 cells in third column ("C"). I have merged each 6 cells in first column ("A"), and unmerged (normal) cells in second column ("B"). I am trying to check for each next cell in row of column "C" if there is a "yes" in first row of column "A" or whether there is a "no" in "A" column and "pass" in "B" column. The trick is, I want to check only first row of "A" column, seventh, thirteenth and nineteenth (so with the step = 6) and check every row in "B" column. I try something like this:

```
Sub try()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    i = 1

    For j = 1 To 12
        With Range("C1:C18")
            .FormatConditions.Delete
            .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=OR(Cells(i, 1) = ""Yes""; AND(Cells(i, 1) = ""No""; Cells(j, 2) = ""Pass""))"

        End With
        If j Mod 6 = 0 Then 
            i = i + 6

    Next j
End Sub
```

But it does not work like that, I saw examples with specific Cells like "A1" or "A3" but I want a number to increase with every loop (so I tried it with Cells(row,column)).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one statement on the whole range by using relative addresses, so what applies to `C1` relatively to `A1` and `B1` will follow automatically in the subsequent rows of the range.

The only trick is to retrieve the value in column `A`, since this value is only available in cells `A1`, `A7`, etc. This is achieved by the expression `OFFSET(A1,-MOD(ROW(C1)-1,6),0)`.

```
Sub doIt()
  With Sheet1.Range("C1:C30").FormatConditions
    .Delete
    .Add(xlExpression, , _
      "=OR(OFFSET(A1,-MOD(ROW(C1)-1,6),0)=""yes"",AND(OFFSET(A1,-MOD(ROW(A1)-1,6),0)=""no"",B1=""pass""))") _
      .Interior.ColorIndex = 6
  End With
End Sub
```

You can also do it from the GUI using the same formula; select cell C1 then select the whole range `C1:C30`, and click

`Conditional Fomatting -> New rule -> Use a formula...` and enter the same formula.

BTW, the expression can be further simplified if you dont care to check for `"no"`, meaning if column A is assured to be either "yes" or "no".

Comment: @Asia The code is fully tested and working exactly as you described. Check if you have `sheet1`, and that you merged regions are: `A1:A6`, `A7:A12`, `A13:A18`, `A19:A24` and `A25:A30`. In your OP there's a mistake stating:  *"first row of "A" column, sixth, twelfth and eighteenth (so with the step = 6)"* if the step is 6 the rows should be `1, 7, 13, 19`, this is what I considered in my answer. But you need to verify it.

Comment: Yes, I meant 1, 7, 13 and 19. But I still get this message: 'Run-time error '5' Invalid procedure call or arument '

Comment: Sorry I can't figure it out. The code works perfectly for me so I don't have any idea what could be going wrong with your setup.